# How to produce stacked bars within grouped barchart in R

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following graph

```
test  <- data.frame(person=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 
                    value1=c(100,150,120,80,150),     
                    value2=c(25,30,45,30,30) , 
                    value3=c(100,120,150,150,200))
```

I want to plot a grouped barchart (horizontal) for each person where one bar indicates value1 and the other bar is stack of value2 and value3.  Is there a way with which I can do this using ggplot2? Can I use facets to plot these individual graphs one below the other?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please share what you have tried so far and how it hasn't worked.  This isn't a place to go and ask us to generate code for you.  Instead, try a few things and formulate a question about your code and how it is or isn't working.

Comment: Downvote comment: Little research effort.

Comment: @SeñorO - you realize I was **NOT** the author of the original question, don't you? I've just edited it

Comment: This question and answer are far more relevant to my problem than the Q&A that this question purportedly duplicates.  Moreover, I think the explanation by @VictorK is easier to understand.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is what I came up with, similar to a solution proposed here: [stacked bars within grouped bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486501/stacked-bars-within-grouped-bar-chart)

1. Melt `data.frame` and add a new column `cat`

   ```
   library(reshape2) # for melt

   melted <- melt(test, "person")

   melted$cat <- ''
   melted[melted$variable == 'value1',]$cat <- "first"
   melted[melted$variable != 'value1',]$cat <- "second"
   ```
2. Plot a stacked chart `cat` vs `value`, faceting by `person`. You may need to adjust the labels to get what you want:

   ```
   ggplot(melted, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
     geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ person)
   ```

[image]

Comment: This is a great plot! Is there a way to alter it so that value 2, for example, can also be stacked onto the "first" bar chart as well? I have a similar plot that has "values" that are included in both "first" and "second", and I do not know how to add it to the plot without making a redundant label on the legend

Comment: Gotta love how easy ggplot makes it to produce pretty graphs. I covered creating stacked / grouped bar charts [here](http://theduke.at/blog/science/beginners-guide-to-creating-grouped-and-stacked-bar-charts-in-r-with-ggplot2/).

Comment: [geom_col()](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html) also makes a plot where the height of the bars represent values in the data. With `geom_col` there is no need to specify `stat = 'identity'`. To generate the plot above: `ggplot(melted, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = variable)) + geom_col() + facet_grid(~ person)`.

Comment: But how to make the same but with with same labels/var for different clusters. Meaning you have `(first - (var1,var2), second - (var1,var2))` for multiple clusters?