# R stacked barplot with groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'd like to create a stacked barchart with groups and am struggling with this:

```
data <- data.frame(timeslot=c("0-1", "1-2", "2-3", "3-4", "4-5", "5-6", "6-7", "7-8", "8-9", "9-10", "10-11", "11-12", "12-13", "13-14", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", "20-21", "21-22", "22-23", "23-0"),
Start1=c(3,0,1,0,0,1,2,22,58,41,30,41,52,52,38,35,20,18,14,19,12,2,9,0),
Start2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,23,11,11,15,19,13,10,13,14,5,4,7,4,3,2,0),
Stop1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,22,17,21,30,29,40,38,43,44,24,40,32,31,22,12,7,12,0),
Stop2=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,5,12,17,12,6,6,17,14,15,9,11,9,11,7,9,3,4,0))
```

*Timeslots* represents 1 hour intervals on a 24h day.
Now, I'd like to have two stacked bars for each interval, i.e. 0-1, 1-2, ..., 23-0.

The numbers in *Start* and *Stop* are counts for processes started and stoped during the given interval.

One bar should be *Start1* and *Start2* (stacked blue bar in image, darker blue for Start1, light blue Start2).
The other bar should be *Stop1* and *Stop2* (stacked brownish bar in image, lighter brown resembles Stop2).

[Picture to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xpkq.png)

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774632/how-to-produce-stacked-bars-within-grouped-barchart-in-r) is similar, but I couldn't get it to work with my data:

```
library(reshape2) # for melt
melted2 <- melt(data, "timeslot")
melted2$cat <- ''
melted2[melted$variable == 'value1',]$cat <- "Start1"
melted2[melted$variable == 'value2',]$cat <- "Start2"
melted2[melted$variable == 'value3',]$cat <- "Stop1"
melted2[melted$variable == 'value4',]$cat <- "Stop2"

ggplot(melted2, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ timeslot)
```

Comment: not sure what melted$variable is, as it isn't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted. As you can see I categorized the four variable types by the two categories "Start" and "Stop".

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(timeslot=c("0-1", "1-2", "2-3", "3-4", "4-5", "5-6", "6-7", "7-8", "8-9", "9-10", "10-11", "11-12", "12-13", "13-14", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", "20-21", "21-22", "22-23", "23-0"),
                   Start1=c(3,0,1,0,0,1,2,22,58,41,30,41,52,52,38,35,20,18,14,19,12,2,9,0),
                   Start2=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,23,11,11,15,19,13,10,13,14,5,4,7,4,3,2,0),
                   Stop1=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,22,17,21,30,29,40,38,43,44,24,40,32,31,22,12,7,12,0),
                   Stop2=c(0,0,0,0,0,1,5,12,17,12,6,6,17,14,15,9,11,9,11,7,9,3,4,0))


library(reshape2) # for melt
melted <- melt(data, "timeslot")
melted$cat <- ''
melted[grep(melted$variable, pattern='Start'),]$cat <- "Start"
melted[grep(melted$variable, pattern='Stop'),]$cat <- "Stop"

melted$timeslot <- factor(melted$timeslot, levels=c("0-1", "1-2", "2-3", "3-4", "4-5", "5-6", "6-7", "7-8", "8-9", "9-10", "10-11", "11-12", "12-13", "13-14", "14-15", "15-16", "16-17", "17-18", "18-19", "19-20", "20-21", "21-22", "22-23", "23-0"))
ggplot(melted, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ timeslot) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("royalblue3", "royalblue1", "#8B4513", "#B8860B")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_text(size=7))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, thats great. Is it possible to prevent the timeslots from being shuffled? They should remain in the order as given in *timeslot*...

Comment: @Geronimo did this answer your question?