# R: Stacked bar graph with two orders of grouping and three columns of data

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping

My colleague and I are trying to create a stacked bar graph that is first grouped by `RIL` (on the x-axis), then by `Trt`, where the `Trt` (treatments) are clumped together and distinguished by colour. We also wish to label each of the bar graphs within each cluster by the treatment `Trt`.

The stacked bar graphs represent the calculated mean of `SW_Before` and `SW_After` (notice there are in the sample data there is one `RIL`, number 206, that has more than one row of data).

I originally thought to combine the two columns of data `SW_Before` and `SW_After`, however the control treatments of `Trt` do not contain data for `SW_Before` and `SW_After` but nevertheless must be included in the graph. Thus, a third column of data from `SW_Total` is graphed for each of the control clusters by `RIL`

I am relatively new to R as well as the realm of data organization so please excuse my amateur capabilities.

Below is a reproducible sample of my data:

```
data1 <- read.table (text= "Plant RIL Trt SW_Before SW_After SW_Total 
1 85 206 Early 0.380 2.27 2.65
2 88 166 Early 0 0.311 0.311
3 92 Lindo Early 0 0.663 0.633
4 94 158 Early 0.0738 0.596 0.669 
5 95 23 Early 0.0252 0.543 0.795
6 97 Lica Early 0 0.646 0.646
7 104 166 Peak 0.227 0.261 0.488
8 108 Lica Peak 0.0705 0.816 0.887
9 113 Lindo Late 0.628 0 0.628
10 115 206 Late 0.544 1.05 1.60
11 115 206 Control NA NA 1.50", sep="", header=T)
```

I realize this graph is more difficult to create than I imagined so any assistance/direction will be most appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I am now trying to graph the average `variable` (which includes `SW_Total`, `SW_Before` and `SW_After`) by `RIL` and `Trt`. This is my code:

```
melted1 <- melt(data.baSW, id=c("Plant", "RIL", "Trt"))
melted1 <- subset(melted1, RIL %in% c("158", "166", "206", "23", "Licalla", "Lindo"))


melted1 %>%
  group_by(Trt, RIL, variable) %>%
  mutate(mean.SW_Total = mean(value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = RIL, y = mean.SW_Total, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ Trt)
```

**EDIT 2**

I have upgraded my code in respond to my EDIT #1. I believe this is the correct code but verification would be nice.

```
melted1 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = RIL, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'summary', position = 'stack', fun.y = "mean") + facet_grid(~ Trt)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure I have interpreted your question correctly but I think this is close to what you want, adjusted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774632/how-to-produce-stacked-bars-within-grouped-barchart-in-r).

```
library(reshape2) # for melt
library(tidyverse)

# convert all total values to 0 except that for the control ...
data1 <- data1 %>%
mutate(SW_Total = ifelse(Trt != "Control", 0, SW_Total))

#convert to long format
melted <- melt(data1, id=c("Plant","RIL","Trt"))

ggplot(melted, aes(x = RIL, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ Trt)
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Except, the data from the Control cluster would come from data column `SW_Total`. How would I add this data for the selected RILs shown in the x-axis? Some data values from the control groups are from RILs that I do not want to include (e.g RIL = 199).

Also - what is the format to dump multiple unused variables?

Comment: @Cam.S I have updated my answer, is this what you mean?

Comment: see this post for dropping variables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605206/drop-data-frame-columns-by-name

Comment: That is what I mean. Hopefully there is another way to do that haha My dataset is much larger and the control rows are sparsed throughout. I will just reorder my dataset via excel.

Comment: @Cam.S I have updated my answer so that `SW_Total` will be replaced with `0` for all rows except `Control` automatically.