# ggplot2 stacked and group barchart together

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I am trying to reproduce this[image]

So far I have [image]

But I need opposite - year below and and countries on the top as labels.

Two SO answers are here

[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774632/how-to-produce-stacked-bars-within-grouped-barchart-in-r) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597278/how-to-plot-a-stacked-and-grouped-bar-chart-in-ggplot)

Code

```
ggplot(ownership, aes(x = Country, y = Percent, fill = Category)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ Year) +
theme_tufte() +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
theme(plot.margin = margin(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, "cm")) +
theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Data

```
> dput(ownership)

structure(list(Country = c("Cote d'Ivoire", "Cote d'Ivoire", 
"Ethiopia", "Ethiopia", "Kenya", "Kenya", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", 
"Senegal", "Senegal", "South Africa", "South Africa", "Uganda", 
"Uganda", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Cote d'Ivoire", "Ethiopia", "Ethiopia", 
"Kenya", "Kenya", "Nigeria", "Nigeria", "Senegal", "Senegal", 
"South Africa", "South Africa", "Uganda", "Uganda", "Cote d'Ivoire", 
"Cote d'Ivoire", "Ethiopia", "Ethiopia", "Kenya", "Kenya", "Nigeria", 
"Nigeria", "Senegal", "Senegal", "South Africa", "South Africa", 
"Uganda", "Uganda"), Year = c(2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 
 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 
 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 
 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 2017, 2014, 
 2017, 2014, 2017), Percent = c(10, 7, 22, 35, 16, 9, 42, 34, 
 9, 11, 56, 50, 9, 9, 5, 7, 0, 0, 39, 47, 2, 5, 3, 10, 13, 17, 
 18, 24, 19, 27, 0, 0, 19, 26, 0, 0, 4, 22, 2, 2, 17, 26), Category = 
 c("Category A", 
 "Category A", "Category A", "Category A", "Category A", "Category A", 
 "Category A", "Category A", "Category A", "Category A", "Category A", 
 "Category A", "Category A", "Category A", "Category B", "Category B", 
 "Category B", "Category B", "Category B", "Category B", "Category B", 
 "Category B", "Category B", "Category B", "Category B", "Category B", 
 "Category B", "Category B", "Category C", "Category C", "Category C", 
 "Category C", "Category C", "Category C", "Category C", "Category C", 
 "Category C", "Category C", "Category C", "Category C", "Category C", 
 "Category C")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -42L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
 Country = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
 "collector")), Year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
 "collector")), Percent = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
 "collector")), Category = structure(list(), class = 
 c("collector_character", 
 "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
 "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Any tips are appreciated!

**UPDATED**

After changing `X = Year` and `facet_grid(~ Country)` I got a better result with some problem on x axis. R treats year differently than I expected. I have 2014 and 2017, it offers me 2014, 2016, 2017.

[image]

Comment: Please update your question with `dput(ownership)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved personally. I added `as.character()` to x axis.

Final code

```
ggplot(ownership, aes(x = as.character(Year), y = Percent, fill = Category)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + facet_grid(~ Country) +
theme_tufte() +
scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Paired") +
theme(axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank()) +
theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12)) +
theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12)) +
theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

Done! Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This gets you close (using simulated data since you didn't provide any):

```r
library(ggplot2)
#make similar data
df <- expand.grid(country = letters[1:4],
                 year = c("2014", "2017"),
                 category = LETTERS[1:3])
df$percent <- runif(nrow(df))


ggplot(df, aes(year, percent, fill = category)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~country, ncol = 4, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I added data. Interesting solution, I will save it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `facet_grid(~ Year)`, this will make two side by side graphs for the two years (as you have now).

You could have a similar graph to the one you want by using a country-year variable, so:

```
ownership$CountryYear <- paste(ownership$Country, ownership$Year)
```

and then:

```
ggplot(ownership, aes(x = CountryYear, y = Percent, fill = Category)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') + 
...
```

But you may have to play around a lot with the labels to get a graph exactly like the one you are aiming for.