# Remove one legend key from a plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, legend

To separate two groups of bar plot, I followed the method by [How to control space between stack bars in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701456/how-to-control-space-between-stack-bars-in-ggplot2)
The main idea is making a dummy raw but shows NA label on x-axis.
The code I'm using:

```
Df %>% 
  bind_rows(data_frame(var1 = "trt99")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=var1, y=value*100, fill = var3)) +

  geom_bar(stat='identity', width=0.3,
       position = position_dodge(width=1))+

  scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.05,0),
                limits = c("Rho(-)", "Rho(+)", "trt99", "Artemia", "Aca(-)", "Aca(+)"),
                breaks = c("Rho(-)", "Rho(+)",    NA  , "Artemia", "Aca(-)", "Aca(+)"),
                labels = c("Rho(-)", "Rho(+)",     " ", "Artemia", "Aca(-)", "Aca(+)"))+

  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
          legend.position = c(0.2,0.9))
```

And I get the figure like:
[image]

My question is: **How can I remove the NA legend key from this plot?**

Comment: perhaps you can remove the NA from the data itself.

Comment: `+scale_colour_discrete(breaks = c("Phytoplankton", "Zooplanlton"), labels = c("Phytoplankton", "Zooplanlton"))`

Comment: @J_F `scale_fill_discrete` instead of `scale_colour_discrete` ?

Comment: @J_F, Thank you very much! I used `scale_fill_discrete(breaks = c("Phytoplankton", "Zooplankton"), labels = c("Phytoplankton", "Zooplankton"))`, it works!

Comment: @bVa you are of course right!

Comment: @Ashish, bVa, Andre Elrico, thank you all!