# I'd like to extend a custom function for barplots so that I can stack the bars

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'd like to make a three-panel figure with each panel containing grouped barplots . And for the third panel I'd like to make the plot stacked. I've found excellent code here: [Simplest way to do grouped barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17721126/simplest-way-to-do-grouped-barplot). I can get everything except for the stacked plot using the elegant solution at the end of this entry.

I tried many iterations of base R code to get a stacked barplot, but kept running into issues with having a dataframe and not a matrix or vector for the height argument. When I converted to a matrix though I lost the factors in my data. I'll put my working code for the other plots below and indicate where I'd like to add the stacked variable.

Here is a sample of my data

```
Population  Sex numsnpsused numoutliers percentoutliers numoutspc1  numoutspc2
all f_and_m 8728    70  0.80    55  15
all f   6613    11  0.17    9   2
all m   9958    151 1.52    91  60
south   f_and_m 7358    51  0.69    15  36
south   f   6547    65  0.99    17  48
south   m   8068    69  0.86    18  51
```

Code:

```
bar <- function(dv, factors, dataframe, percentage=FALSE, errbar=!percentage, half.errbar=TRUE, conf.level=.95, 
                xlab=NULL, ylab=NULL, main=NULL, names.arg=NULL, bar.col="black", whisker=.015,args.errbar=NULL,
                legend=TRUE, legend.text=NULL, args.legend=NULL,legend.border=FALSE, box=TRUE, args.yaxis=NULL, 
                mar=c(5,4,3,2),...){
  axes=!percentage
  dv.name<-substitute(dv)
  if(length(dv.name)>1) stop("'dv' only takes one variable")
  dv.name<-as.character(dv.name)
  dv<-dataframe[[dv.name]]
  fnames<-substitute(factors)
  if(length(fnames)==1){
    factors<-as.character(fnames)
    nf<-1
  }else{
    factors<-as.character(fnames[-1L])
    nf<-length(factors)
  }
  if(nf>2) stop("This function accepts no more than 2 factors \n",
                "\t-i.e., it only plots one-way or two-way designs.")
  if(percentage & errbar){
    warning("percentage=TRUE; error bars were not plotted")
    errbar<-FALSE
  }
  if(!percentage) xbars<-tapply(dv, dataframe[,factors], mean, na.rm=TRUE)
  else {
    xbars<-tapply(dv, list(interaction(dataframe[,factors], lex.order=TRUE)), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
    if(sum(na.omit(dv)!=0&na.omit(dv)!=1)>0) 
      stop("Data points in 'dv' need to be 0 or 1 in order to set 'percentage' to TRUE")
    xbars<-rbind(xbars, 1-xbars)*100
  }
  if(errbar){
    se<-tapply(dv, dataframe[,factors], sd, na.rm=TRUE)/sqrt(tapply(dv, dataframe[,factors], length))
    conf.level=1-(1-conf.level)/2
    lo.bar<-xbars-se*qnorm(conf.level)
    hi.bar<-xbars+se*qnorm(conf.level)  
  }
  extras<-list(...)
  if(legend & !percentage){
    if(is.null(legend.text))
      legend.text<-sort(unique(dataframe[[factors[1]]]))
    args.legend.temp<-list(x="topright", bty=if(!legend.border)"n" else "o",
                           inset=c(0,0))
    if(is.list(args.legend))
      args.legend<-modifyList(args.legend.temp, args.legend)
    else 
      args.legend<-args.legend.temp
  } else if(legend & percentage){
    if(is.null(legend.text)) 
      legend.text<-c("1", "0")
    args.legend.temp<-list(x="topright", bty=if(!legend.border)"n" else "o",
                           inset=c(0,0))
    if(is.list(args.legend))
      args.legend<-modifyList(args.legend.temp, args.legend)
    else 
      args.legend<-args.legend.temp
  } else if(!legend){
    args.legend<-NULL
    legend.text<-NULL
  }
  if(errbar && legend && !percentage) ymax<-max(hi.bar)+max(hi.bar)/20
  else if(errbar && legend && percentage) ymax<-115
  else if(errbar && !legend) ymax <- max(xbars)
  else if(!errbar && legend && percentage) ymax<-110    
  else if(!errbar) ymax<-max(xbars) + max(xbars)/20
  if(!percentage){
    args.barplot<-list(beside=TRUE, height=xbars, ylim=c(0, ymax), main=main, names.arg=names.arg,
                       col=hcl(h=seq(0,270, 270/(length(unique(dataframe[[factors[1]]]))))[-length(unique(dataframe[[factors[1]]]))]),
                       legend.text=legend.text, args.legend=args.legend, xpd=TRUE,
                       xlab=if(is.null(xlab)) factors[length(factors)] else xlab,
                       ylab=if(is.null(ylab)) dv.name else ylab, axes=axes)
  }else{
    args.barplot<-list(beside=TRUE, height=xbars, ylim=c(0, ymax),  main=main, names.arg=names.arg,
                       col=hcl(h=seq(0,270, 270/(length(unique(dataframe[[factors[1]]]))))[-length(unique(dataframe[[factors[1]]]))]),
                       legend.text=legend.text, args.legend=args.legend, xpd=TRUE,
                       xlab=if(is.null(xlab)) " "[length(factors)] else xlab,
                       ylab=if(is.null(ylab)) "percentage" else ylab, axes=axes)        
  }
  args.barplot<-modifyList(args.barplot, extras)
  errbars = function(xvals, cilo, cihi, whisker, nc, args.errbar = NULL, half.errbar=TRUE) {
    if(half.errbar){
      cilo<-(cihi+cilo)/2
    }
    fixedArgs.bar = list(matlines, x=list(xvals), 
                         y=lapply(split(as.data.frame(t(do.call("rbind", 
                                                                list(cihi, cilo)))),1:nc),matrix, 
                                  nrow=2, byrow=T))
    allArgs.bar = c(fixedArgs.bar, args.errbar)
    whisker.len = whisker*(par("usr")[2] - par("usr")[1])/2
    whiskers = rbind((xvals - whisker.len)[1,],
                     (xvals + whisker.len)[1,])
    fixedArgs.lo = list(matlines, x=list(whiskers),     
                        y=lapply(split(as.data.frame(t(do.call("rbind", 
                                                               list(cilo, cilo)))), 1:nc), matrix, nrow=2, byrow=T))
    allArgs.bar.lo = c(fixedArgs.lo, args.errbar)
    fixedArgs.hi = list(matlines, x=list(whiskers), 
                        y=lapply(split(as.data.frame(t(do.call("rbind", 
                                                               list(cihi, cihi)))), 1:nc), matrix, nrow=2, byrow=T))
    allArgs.bar.hi = c(fixedArgs.hi, args.errbar)  
    invisible(do.call(mapply, allArgs.bar))
    if(!half.errbar) invisible(do.call(mapply, allArgs.bar.lo))
    invisible(do.call(mapply, allArgs.bar.hi))
  }
  par(mar=mar)
  errloc<-as.vector(do.call(barplot, args.barplot))
  if(errbar){
    errloc<-rbind(errloc, errloc)
    lo.bar<-matrix(as.vector(lo.bar))
    hi.bar<-matrix(as.vector(hi.bar))
    args.errbar.temp<-list(col=bar.col, lty=1)
    args.errbar<-if(is.null(args.errbar)|!is.list(args.errbar)) 
      args.errbar.temp
    else if(is.list(args.errbar)) 
      modifyList(args.errbar.temp, args.errbar)
    errbars(errloc, cilo=lo.bar, cihi=hi.bar, nc=1, whisker=whisker, 
            args.errbar=args.errbar, half.errbar=half.errbar)
  }
  if(box) box()
  if(percentage){
    args.yaxis.temp<-list(at=seq(0,100, 20), las=1)
    args.yaxis<-if(!is.list(args.yaxis)) args.yaxis.temp else modifyList(args.yaxis.temp, args.yaxis)
    do.call(axis, c(side=2, args.yaxis))
  }
}

bar(dv = numsnpsused, 
    factors = c(Sex, Population), 
    dataframe = WALL, 
    errbar = FALSE, 
    col=c("red","purple","blue"),
    ylab=c("Number of SNPs used in analysis"),
    ylim=c(0, 12000))  #I increased the upper y-limit to accommodate the legend. 

parpar(mfrow=c(2,2))    
bar(dv = percentoutliers, 
    factors = c(Sex, Population), 
    dataframe = WALL, 
    errbar = FALSE, 
    col=c("red","purple","blue"),
    ylab=c("% of SNPs that were outliers"),
    ylim=c(0,3))  #I increased the upper y-limit to accommodate the legend.

##I want to include a second variable to stack in this plot
bar(dv = numoutspc1, 
    factors = c(Sex, Population), 
    dataframe = WALL, 
    errbar = FALSE, 
    col=c("red","purple","blue"),
    ylab=c("Number of outliers associated with each PCaxis"),
    ylim=c(0, 240))  #I increased the upper y-limit to accommodate the legend.
```

Here is the plot that I made[image: The two plots on top are what I want, but the one on the bottom only has the bottom half of each bar. I want to add another variable on top]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to provide a good answer without more details and what graph you expect as output. Here is a solution using `ggplot2` that might start you off. You can imitate the grouped bar plot by merging the two grouping variables while still stacking by another variable.

```r
df <- data.frame(y=sample(c(2000:2002),1000,T), k=sample(letters[1:3],1000,T),
                 g=sample(c(1:2),1000,T),
                 c=sample(c('t','f'),1000,T),stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>% count(y,k,g,c) %>% mutate(k1=paste0(k,g)) %>% 
  filter(y==2002|c!='f') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(k1,n,fill=c)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') + facet_wrap(~y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486501/stacked-bars-within-grouped-bar-chart)

Comment: Thanks. Just went through the code you linked to, and it does the job