# How do I create a stacked bar chart in ggplot2 with grouped y values?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to create a stacked bar chart in RStudio using ggplot2. I want Year on the x-axis with stacked bars based on revenue values for Recorded Music, Music Publishing, and Live Music.

**My data:**

| Year | Recorded Music | Music Publishing | Live Music |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2014 | 13.4 | 11.3 | 24.2 |
| 2015 | 14 | 10.4 | 25.2 |
| 2016 | 15.2 | 11.2 | 25.8 |
| 2017 | 16.6 | 11.5 | 26.7 |
| 2018 | 18.1 | 11.5 | 27.9 |
| 2019 | 19.6 | 12.1 | 28.6 |
| 2020 | 21.1 | 11.4 | 7.3 |

**My code so far:**

```
ggplot(data = Music_Rev_Data, aes(x=Year, y = ????))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

I don't know how to group the y variables/objects and it's driving me insane - I'm obviously new to R.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13486501/stacked-bars-within-grouped-bar-chart

Comment: I don't think so, the y = values would require all values be in one column whereas I have them split by sectors.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
Music_Rev_Data %>%
  pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = "type") %>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, value, fill = type)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, can you explain what's going on in your code? You're converting to long form, creating a type column for the names, but don't you need to deal with the values? Appreciate the answer.

Comment: `aes()` by default has x and y as the first two parameters, so `aes(Year, value, fill = type)` is the same as `aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = type)`. "value" was the default name for the values reshaped in the pivot_longer step.

Comment: Ah okay. One last question, why is there a (-) sign before Year?

Comment: That's in the spot where we specify which columns should be pivoted longer. We can either specify which columns we want to pivot (e.g. `pivot_longer('Recorded Music':'Live Music', ....`) or which columns we don't want to pivot (e.g. not Year, or `pivot_longer(-Year, ...`)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative stacked bar graph that shows the value for each category in the sample variable.

Sample code:

```
    library(ggplot2)
    
  df<-reshape2::melt(Music_Rev_Data, id.var = c("Year")) 
  
  df$variable=factor(df$variable, levels=c("Live.Music", "Music.Publishing", "Record.Music"))
  
  ggplot(df, aes(Year, value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill()) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name="Type", labels=c("Live music","Music publishing","Record music"))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(x="Year", y="%", fill="Type")+
  geom_text(aes(label = value), position = position_fill(vjust = .5),  size=9)+
  theme_minimal()+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
          axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
          axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
          strip.text = element_text(size=10, face="bold"),
          plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=20, face="bold"),
          legend.text = element_text( color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
          legend.position="bottom",
          legend.box = "horizontal",
          legend.title = element_blank())
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
Music_Rev_Data<-structure(list(Year = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020
), Record.Music = c(13.4, 14, 15.2, 16.6, 18.1, 19.6, 21.1), 
    Music.Publishing = c(11.3, 10.4, 11.2, 11.5, 11.5, 12.1, 
    11.4), Live.Music = c(24.2, 25.2, 25.8, 26.7, 27.9, 28.6, 
    7.3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```